# SQL Server UNION change the order of query in results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I triying to make a union of 2 queries in SQL Server. I want that the second querie row stay at the final of the results, but it returns in a first place.

Query:

```
SELECT 
name,
total
FROM persons

UNION

SELECT 
'TOTAL' as name
SUM(total) as total,
from persons
```

The result that a get:

```
name    total
TOTAL   200
John    100
Matt    100
```

The result that I want:

```
name    total
John    100
Matt    100
TOTAL   200
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the rows on a specific order you need to use `ORDER BY`.

In the absence of an `ORDER BY` clause a relational database will provide the rows in any unspecified order; the rows may show up in the order you want today, but that may change tomorrow.

For example, you can do:

```
select name, total
from (
  SELECT name, total, 1 as display_order
  FROM persons
 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TOTAL', SUM(total), 2
  FROM persons
) x
ORDER BY display_order
```

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED
I used union all instead union

Comment: Well, you probably should have been using UNION ALL to start with, but (a) changing from UNION *could* change the results (since UNION also filters out duplicates), and (b) UNION ALL does not guarantee order any more than UNION does. You don't have an ORDER BY, so SQL Server could still produce the results in any way. Just because it's returning the result the way you want it now, that's just a happy coincidence, and tje behavior could change tomorrow.

Comment: This answer won't produce the rows in the expected order. As @AaronBertrand says it's a happy coincidence that the rows showed up as you wanted *this time*.